# Windows Office 2010 and Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, laptop, microsoft-word-2010

When I open WORD, I get a message that "Microsoft WORD has stopped working".  I have tried to delete normal.dotx, also renaming the toolbar key in regedit and also checking my default printer.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If the fix offered by ricbax does not work, try an office repair

To Repair Office 2010:

Open Control Panel and click Programs and Features.

Right click the Office 2010 program that you want to repair, and select Change.

Next click Repair > Continue.

Restart your computer.

http://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-repair-office-2010-or-uninstall-individual-office-2010-programs

.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve your issue, you can follow the methods below to delete the corresponding registry:

1. Click Start , type regedit in the Start Search box, and then press ENTER.
2. If you are prompted for an administrator password or for a confirmation, type the password, or click Continue.
3. Backup your registry!
4. Locate and then click the following registry subkey:
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Word\Data
5. On the Edit menu, click Delete, and then click Yes.
6. Exit Registry Editor.
7. Restart Word

Do you recall if you installed any add-ons that may not be compatible with Word 2010? If so, uninstall them and see if that might also correct the issue.

Comment: I deleted the registry subkey as you suggested, restarted Word and it still gave me the same error message (Microsoft Word not working).  @Moab  -  I tried repairing Office 2010 per your instruction.  Still getting the same error message.  Any other suggestions?